# How do I remove a Vagrant box from global-status, after deleting that box from the filesystem?

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox

I deleted a folder containing a running Vagrant box before realising it was still running.

How can I delete it from Vagrant (global-status) now?

I already removed the Virtualbox VM.

Comment: Whether the Vagrant VM is running or not doesn't matter (I recently found this out). Even if the VM is stopped, if you manually delete its files instead of running `vagrant destroy`, `vagrant global-status` will still report the "host state unknown" problem.

Answer (score 204, accepted):

To discard old boxes listed in `vagrant global-status` (eg. you deleted the folder containing the `.vagrant` dir from the filesystem) you just need to run:

```
vagrant global-status --prune
```

You might need to remove the Virtual Machine directly from your provider (VMWare, Virtualbox, ..) control interface.

Comment: I created the problem for myself in reverse: I deleted the VM's files from the provider, and also changed the Vagrantfile so that the VM was no longer part of the project's Vagrant configuration. The `--prune` option worked for my scenario as well. Thanks!

Comment: It worked for me only from inside an existing running Vagrant provisioned VM.

Comment: Didn't work for me.  I had to manually edit `~/.vagrant.d/data/machine-index` and remove the offending entry.

Comment: This worked for my case. If you change your machine name and the old one (that don't work anymore) still listed by vagrant global-status.

Answer (score 6):

I believe that the new filename of the global data is `~/.vagrant.d`.

So you can run `rm -r ~/.vagrant.d` to delete all user data for a fresh start.

Answer (score 0):

For my case: Where kitchen and .kitchen/ folder may contain hidden vagrant files create by

```
$ kitchen create
```

I need to go further than either kitchen destroy or vagrant destroy or even vagrant destroy machineID ( from vagrant global-status - which gives a list of vagrant instances across your user space. )

In my case, I had to blow away the vagrant machine lock files contained in the users .vagrant hidden directory.

```
$ rm -r ~/.vagrant/data
```

And in my case I need to sudo the above command.

Then I finally got to a clean

```
$ vagrant global-status
```

list

Answer (score 0):

First you use `vagrant global-status` to list all the vagrant machines and their status and `ids`.

then you can use:

```
 vagrant destroy -f the_id_of_the_machine
```

after that if you run `vagrant global-status` again you will find that the id you have specified in the `vagrant destroy -f` command has been removed from the list.

and then you might need to restart your machine However these commands will not affect your boxes.

Answer (score 0):

The above commands didn't remove the old box in my case on a Windows machine. I had already removed the `.vagrant` folder and the box from the virtualbox provider folder but the box was still in the `vagrant global-status list`.

As mentioned in the comment given by a `vagrant up` command:

```
If you believe this message is in error, please check the process
listing for any "ruby" or "vagrant" processes and kill them. Then
try again.
```

So I killed `ruby.exe` from the process list and did a subsequent `vagrant global-status --prune`.